# Recording Separate Contributions in a Membership Webform

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, contributions, donations

Working on a Civi 4.5.5 site. I've configured a membership renewal contribution page to record a membership fee, and (voluntary) additional donation.

By setting the Contribution Page Financial Type to "Donation", and selecting "Separate Membership Payment" on the Membership tab. When entering a test payment, two contribution records were created with one of type "Donation" and one of type "Membership Fee". As expected.

Renewal is easy, because we are only capturing info for the Primary member.

The membership type extends by relationship to other family members. so the organisation want a membership webform to capture contact details of the related individuals (spouse//partner, and offspring) on initial sign up.

When testing the webform to collect an additional donation on sign up, only 1 contribution was recorded (equal to the value of the membership fee and the donation- but labelled as a donation).

Is it just that the create separate payments option doesn't work with the current civi/webform integration? In which case I need to discuss what is more important with the organisation.

Or am I missing something blindingly obvious? Has anyone been able to get this to work?

*thought of this after pressing save*
Should I collect related contact data in the webform, then re-direct to membership contribution page which will populate with Contact 1's data and allow the separate payments to work as expected?

Cheers

Craig

Comment: Did you enable the "contribution amount" field on the webform?

Comment: Hi Coleman,

Yes Contribution amount is added.

Craig

Comment: Hi Coleman and Pete

Thanks for your input 

I think the form won't quite do what I want. Talking to the client, they are happy that the form does take a membership payment and an additional donation, and are satisfied with that functionality.

I wanted to split payment into two contribution records so that the donation could be further processed for Gift Aid.

To get all the features I'd have to create a webform for contact details and a contribution page for the payments and customise the redirect link from one to the other. Which is currently beyond my capabilities.

Comment: I think you'll find certain civi reports will allow you to drill down into the individual line-items being created under the umbrella of that single contribution record.

Answer (score 6):

Webform-CiviCRM integration was designed to be able to sign up multiple members plus collect a contribution. It will save a single contribution record containing a separate line-item for each (2 memberships + a donation = 3 line items).

There are some key settings that are required:

- Contributions (in Webform CiviCRM section): Should be set to your Donation Contribution page and *not* your Membership Contribution page if you created one
- Memberships Tab (in Webform CiviCRM section): Should be set to one

With those settings above and any other data that you would like to collect you will be able to receive a donation and membership purchase on the same transaction.

Adding some examples:

[image]

So on a contribution level these look like Donations -> so you must pull LineItem reports; this one is a good one (from Fuzion's Extended Reports): civicrm/report/price/contributionbased?reset=1

[image]

Adding some more screenshots:

Contribution page config (also enabled a Payment Processor); but I don't even have Membership section enabled here;

[image]

Webform CiviCRM config [I've hidden Membership type as there really is only one];

[image]

Comment: On the tests I ran, it created a single contribution (financial type donation) 
the contribution record didn't break this down further (m'ship fee + donation)


Running a payment directly through the linked contribution page created two separate contribution records.

Comment: As far as I can see, when we set up a webform to take payment for both an event and a membership, we got a single contribution with a single line item. Perhaps there is something both Craig and I are missing in the webform set up.

Comment: That's odd, it's certainly *supposed* to create line items for each entity.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we are using this for a client and creating the line items. Let me see if there was anything bespoke done. J

Comment: Webform creates separate line items when you pay for different items. I can confirm this under the environment of Civi4.6.8 + latest webform civicrm module.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect Webform does not handled that, so yes you might need to either do the Membership page, then pass them on to a Webform to add their related people, or vv